# I have installed ipython ,but could not open it

Tags: ipython

'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have tried reinstalling python with add python to path optin .But that didn't work either.

'ipython' input

'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

just install ipython from terminal

```
pip install ipython
```

after that run this in terminal

```
ipython
```

Comment: Tried it ,but still gets the same output.